# Matrix Rotation with three Angles

Tags: matrix, rotation, linear-algebra, angles, glm

I want to rotate a form with three given angles fo each of the three axis. But the [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) `rotation` function takes only one angle and a vector as arguments.

How can I convert between both formats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLM's rotation function uses [Euler's rotation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem), which implies that any rotation or sequence of rotations of a rigid body in a three-dimensional space is equivalent to a pure rotation about a single fixed axis.

However consecutive calls to GLMs rotate function just multiply the rotation so rotating a rigid body by Yaw, Pitch, Roll is as simple as this:

```
glRotateF(yaw, 0, 1, 0);
glRotateF(pitch, 1, 0, 0);
glRotateF(roll, 0, 0, 1);
```

Edit: please also read [this article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/quaternion-powers-r1095) where they explain the differences and how you can go from Euler angles to Quaternions to Axis Angle  :)

Answer (score 1):

The angles used to build a rotation for each of the three axes are known as [Tait-Bryan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) angles (often confused with Euler angles).

Wikipedia has [all the formulas you need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Matrix_orientation) to convert Euler or Tait-Bryan angles into a rotation matrix.

Here is some code to build a rotation matrix from three Tait-Bryan angles and the order of the rotations:

```
/* i, j and k are the integers 0, 1 and 2 in any order.
 * For instance passing 1, 2, 0 will first rotate around
 * Y, then Z, then X.
 * Make sure to convert from degrees to radians if necessary. */
mat3 tait_brian_to_matrix(float a, float b, float c,
                          int i, int j, int k)
{
    mat3 ret;

    float s0 = sin(a), c0 = cos(a);
    float s1 = sin(b), c1 = cos(b);
    float s2 = sin(c), c2 = cos(c);

    ret[i][i] =   c1 * c2;
    ret[k][k] =   c0 * c1;

    if ((2 + i - j) % 3)
    {
        ret[j][i] = - c1 * s2;
        ret[k][i] =   s1;

        ret[i][j] =   c0 * s2 + s0 * s1 * c2;
        ret[j][j] =   c0 * c2 - s0 * s1 * s2;
        ret[k][j] = - s0 * c1;

        ret[i][k] =   s0 * s2 - c0 * s1 * c2;
        ret[j][k] =   s0 * c2 + c0 * s1 * s2;
    }
    else
    {
        ret[j][i] =   c1 * s2;
        ret[k][i] = - s1;

        ret[i][j] = - c0 * s2 + s0 * s1 * c2;
        ret[j][j] =   c0 * c2 + s0 * s1 * s2;
        ret[k][j] =   s0 * c1;

        ret[i][k] =   s0 * s2 + c0 * s1 * c2;
        ret[j][k] = - s0 * c2 + c0 * s1 * s2;
    }
    return ret;
}
```